# Constants in Limits

Tags: limits

is the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{ax}{ax+b}$ just $a(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{ax+b})$ or is it possible for the constant to remain inside?

Comment: @graydad Yes, my mistake.

Comment: Both statements are true. The two limits you wrote are equal, but you can also take the limit without extracting the factor of $a$, since $\frac{ax}{ax+b} = 1 - \frac{b}{ax + b}$.

Comment: @DavidK If those two ways would yield different results which should be done?  Please see the comment below in the answers.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to think of a good example where you get different results. You might find that one of the manipulations is simply invalid (so you get _no_ result from it, not a different result) but even there I'm coming up blank for an example. You might think $a=0$ would create a problem but in your question it just means the result comes out to $0$ in either case. (There _is_ a problem if $a=b=0$: _none_ of the limits are defined in that case!)

Comment: @DavidK My concern is that you suggest the result would be zero if $a=0$ but I think it would actually be undefined considering the formula I wrote in the comments below.

Comment: OK, now I see what you mean. Don't do that. The other ways still work, for example what you wrote in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is proved in calculus courses that, if $\lim_{x \to *} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\lim_{x \to *} af(x)=a \lim_{x \to *} f(x)$. However this rule may be troublesome if we allow infinite limits, since we must exclude the case $a=0$.

Comment: So the limit is really the limit of $\frac{x}{x+\frac{b}{a}}$, right?

Comment: Yes (unless $a=0$)

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $s_n\to s$ converges, then $as_n\to as$, where $a$ is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If in this case $a$ is a constant and $a \neq0$ then you can factor it out. The limit is with respect to x so $a$ does not affect it

Comment: So the limit is really the limit of $\frac{x}{x+\frac{b}{a}}$, right?